# Unreadable database error using ODBC

Tags: python, sql-server, odbc, pyodbc, freetds

I'm using pypyodbc and FreeTDS to connect to SQL Server 2008.  I occasionally get errors but I can't ever read the error message.  I've tried decoding the string from UTF-8 and it is still illegible.  Does anyone know how I can get human readable error messages?

This is my connection string:

```
conn = pypyodbc.connect('DRIVER=FreeTDS;SERVER=myserver;PORT=1433;DATABASE=mydb;UID=myuid;PWD=mypw;CHARSET=UTF-8;TDS_Version=8.0;', unicode_results=True)
```

This is the error message:

```
pypyodbc.DatabaseError: (u'\u3130\u30300', u'[\u3130\u30300] \u755b\u696e\u4f78\u4244\u5d43\u445b\u6972\u6576\u2072\u614d\u616e\u6567\u5d72\u6143\u276e\u2074\u706f\u6e65\u6c20\u6269\u2720\u752f\u7273\u6c2f\u6269\u782f\u3638\u365f\u2d34\u696c\u756e\u2d78\u6e67\u2f75\u646f\u6362\u6c2f\u6269\u6474\u6f73\u6264\u2e63\u6f73\u2027\u203a\u6966\u656c\u6e20\u746f\u6620\u756f\u646e')
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the error string is stored in the unicode object as UTF-16.  Calling encode('utf-16LE') on the error string gave me a readable string back.